# Visual Studio will not recognize Unity modules

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am a complete beginner to Unity, as well as Visual Studio 2022.

I was trying to make a 2D game, and have been following along this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM. At 25:11, we are shown how to make a script to control the player movement. While I was going to use Visual Studio Code, the Unity debugger for VScode is deprecated, and no longer functions.

To solve this I switched to Visual Studio 2022. I installed the 'Game Development with Unity' and the '.NET desktop development' modules, and set the default external editor within Unity to Visual Studio 2022. I also regenerated the .csproj files as I was instructed in another form.

Despite this, I encounter `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InputValue' could not be found` (27:29 in the video, I am using the 'Player Input' module from Unity)
[image]

The libraries also do not light up green, but I am not sure if that is just a theme difference between us, but this is a clean install with the default dark mode.

Comment: there are 2 different editors, don't expect them to look the same.

Comment: I still get the error though. And the reason I point it out is that my class definition PlayerController, is green yet everything else isnt. If there is a theme setting to change this could you please help me find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[At 22:20 in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM&t=22m20s) they get the Input System package from the Package Manager.

[The documentation for InputValue](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.9/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputValue.html) says it's from the UnityEngine.InputSystem namespace, so when you see the error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InputValue' could not be found

It's the compiler telling you it can't find the namespace where InputValue is defined.

To solve this problem, you need to add a "using" statement at the top of the file to tell the compiler where to find that function.

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
```

Their code won't work without it, either and actually [at 31:50 in the same video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM&t=31m50s) you see them realize the error and correct it as well.